# Using technology in Physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, software, big-list, technology

Currently I find that technology is a wonderful tool in efficiently understanding physics. It helps in giving access to resources and providing a better understanding of topics but what I dislike is slowly figuring out that this resource “could have changed everything” I’ve been doing till now because it was “a secret that only few knew of “.

So I wanted some secrets others have been using for long which they're sure will help others as well. I'm looking for things such as online-simulators, physics 'news' websites, chat forums etc.

What aspects of technology (or for that matter-resources in general) have you been using that have enabled you to become better at understanding physics?

Comment: In its current form the question is quite quite broad and opinion based. You should try to make it a bit narrower and less opinion based otherwise this might be closed.

Comment: @JohanLiebert I've narrowed it down with a few examples. Hope that does it!

Answer (score 1):

Mandatory listing, I guess:-

1. https://arxiv.org/archive/physics
2. https://www.researchgate.net/

I’ll update if anything better comes over time.

Comment: A significant fraction of the material on ResearchGate would never be accepted for publication in a legitimate physics journal. I have not investigated whether they enforce any standards, but I do not detect any in what I have seen there. Of course it is not *all* fringe stuff. But I have seen enough fringe stuff that I suggest being wary about what you read there.

Answer (score 0):

As a response to what I wish to focus on, here are the things I find helpful in my learning of Physics:-

1. Physics StackExchange
2. r/Physics-Fun physics to explore on reddit.com
3. quantumdiaries.org-To keep up to date with physics (I need something better to replace this).
4. The various chat forums on the Art of Problem Solving(AoPS)-To discuss, a bit more freely, various problems and questions regarding physics/science.
5. MIT OCW/edX lectures
6. Online youtube resources (from Walter Lewin to MinutePhysics to Veritasium).
7. COURSERA courses (which I'll admit I haven't used as much).

I figured I might as well go personal so here's a little something extra:-

1. I have pdf's of books which I review before buying (if ever). These pdfs are from other online resources but a specific resource would be the Telegram communication app where 'channels' send multiple pdfs of various books. This is extremely helpful to use before buying a book.